Minimizing the function of a single variable depending on the parameter in MathCAD
I have a function of the variable x with the parameter p: f(x,p)=x^2+p*x. I am creating a vector of parameters p_i = 0.1 * i where i from 0 to 49. I need to find minimum of the function f(x,p_i) for each fixed value of the parameter p_i, so that I get a vector of minimum values of the function of 50 elements at the output. How can I implement this in MathCAD?
